# SELECT * FROM (tablename) WHERE (array values) = '1'

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have this question about SQL queries.

Here its is:

```
$allowed = array("Amsterdam", "Arnhem", "Assen", "Groningen", "Leeuwarden", "Rotterdam", "Sittard", "Tilburg", "Utrecht");

$filter = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE '$allowed' = '1'");
$filter->execute;

foreach($filter->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $filtered):

    $amsterdam = $filtered->amsterdam;
    $arnhem = $filtered->arnhem;
    $assen = $filtered->assen;
    $groningen = $filtered->groningen;
    $leeuwarden = $filtered->leeuwarden;
    $rotterdam = $filtered->rotterdam;
    $sittard = $filtered->sittard;
    $utrecht = $filtered->utrecht;

endforeach;
```

The output (when echoed) is blank.

How can I get the query to look for column names from the array?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to add `OR` parts;

Comment: Have you enabled the errors in the `php.ini' file? Have you tested the query in the SQL server before going to the code?

Comment: One more thing `execute` is a method not property so it should be `$filter->execute();`;

Comment: Yes you need `OR` parts to achieve your goal, but another question: What is your purpose? Looks like it might be reasonable to overthink the DB structure.

Comment: Look into changing your db design,each city with a column name is extremely inefficient,nevermind problems like the above.

Comment: See normalisation. Fix your design. The suggestions below are essentially worse than useless

Comment: It is something like I want users to have specific rights to the districts in the array $allowed. So i want the query to filter this. But instead of typing all the districts I want to know if it's possible to use WHERE $allowed = '1' (so they are allowed)

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE id = '{$userId}'");
        $query->execute();

```
    foreach($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $value){  

        $districts = array("amsterdam","arnhem","assen","groningen","leeuwarden","rotterdam","sittard","tilburg","utrecht","antillen","missie","dap","sap");
        $arrlength = count($districts);

        for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {

            if($value->$districts[$x] == TRUE){
                echo '<pre>';
                echo ucfirst($districts[$x]) . ' --> ' . $value->$districts[$x];
                echo '</pre>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using it in if($value->$districts[$x] == TRUE){